# Curl stops with error on long lasting SSL Connections

Tags: curl

I need to connect with https to a server, the server will compute a very long computation ( > 5 min). To simulate the connection I made a spring mvc controller that sleeps for a while.

When I start the request after 5 minutes I get an error from curl. So on linux with curl I get:

```
-bash-4.1$ curl -v --tlsv1 --keepalive-time 330 -X POST -F "sec=310" https://example.com/general/sleep
* About to connect() to example.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying <ip>... connected
* Connected to example.com (<ip>) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=*.example.com,OU=Gandi Standard Wildcard SSL,OU=Domain Control Validated
*       start date: Apr 29 00:00:00 2015 GMT
*       expire date: Jul 28 23:59:59 2018 GMT
*       common name: *.example.com
*       issuer: CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA 2,O=Gandi,L=Paris,ST=Paris,C=FR
> POST /general/sleep HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.21 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 141
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------e2ab66c15d1a
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* SSL read: errno -5961
* Closing connection #0
curl: (56) SSL read: errno -5961
```

On [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) the same request works. The request also works if the connection is shorter than 5 minutes.

The same (but with a slightly different error message) also happens with curl under cygwin on windows:

```
$ curl -v --tlsv1 --keepalive-time 330 -X POST -F "sec=310" https://example.com/general/sleep
Warning: Keep-alive functionality somewhat crippled due to missing support in
Warning: your operating system!
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x6000574b0; line 1075 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
*   Trying 193.73.238.220...
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x6000574b0; line 1128 (connection #0)
* Connected to example.com (<ip>) port 443 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x6000574b0; line 1225 (connection #0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x6000574b0; line 1239 (connection #0)
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*        subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=Gandi Standard Wildcard SSL; CN=*.example.com
*        start date: 2015-04-29 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2018-07-28 23:59:59 GMT
*        subjectAltName: example.com matched
*        issuer: C=FR; ST=Paris; L=Paris; O=Gandi; CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA 2
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
* STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x6000574b0; line 1260 (connection #0)
> POST /general/sleep HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 141
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------0e215aa5d70f368d
>
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x6000574b0; line 1322 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x6000574b0; line 1449 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x6000574b0; line 1459 (connection #0)
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104
* Curl_done
* Closing connection 0
* The cache now contains 0 members
curl: (56) SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104
```

Comment: May be it's related to red hat bug Bug 895339.  "This issue is being tracked by Red hat under Bug 895339. Please contact Red Hat Global Support Services to enquire as to the status of this bug."

Comment: thanks @gile, but I have no rights to access bug 895339 in the red hat bug tracker. I have the same problem under cgwin, I added the output.

Comment: May be it helps http://www.naulinux.ru/static/Docs/SLCE/6.7/Docs/SL/Technical.Notes.66.html or https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/nss-pem.git/commit/?id=b754c62f815409fc276b70c114fb63a3a863a79d

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why it did work with postman. But the problem was that the involved BigIP Firewall has a default timeout of 300 s on connection and it did kill the connection.